# Oracle 12 SQL - ORA-00933, ORA-0923, ORA-00979 What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am currently facing a bit of a wall, I am attempting to take information from two different tables, have them displayed side by side with the information recording by count. One being the total amount in the first table with a specific value, the second is the value of different column.

Table A.current is the same as B.id

However the information I want is total of hits in table A with current and display the information of B.name instead of b.id

I've attempted many things, so far I keep having an issue where it says about from is incorrect or group is incorrect:

```
select  
    count(pk.id) as "Total",
    lc.fullyqualifiedname as "Name"
from
    tsu pk,
    location lc
where   
    pk.locationid = lc.id
group by 
    lc.id
having 
    lc.id  = :ID;
```

From the code above I get the error 00923

If anyone could help me - where did I go wrong?

What I need to end up with would be

Column 1 - total of hits ( count(*) ) which have location as lc.id
Column 2 - the name which the lc.id is represented as fullyqualifiedname being displayed. providing the value of a different column in the sable table.

EDIT :

```
select  count(pk.id) as "Total",
    lc.fullyqualifiedname as "Name"
from    tsu pk,
    location lc
where   pk.locationid = lc.id
group by lc.id
having lc.id  = :ID;
```

This script works however it displays column 1 from table lc, I would like to have column name from lc display.

-- Issue is resolved with answered script.

Comment: how can you give alias name for lc.*?

Comment: for first query use lc.fullyqualifiedname instead of lc.id in the group by clause and change having clause to where clause

Comment: @Gaj When I do so I get Name = number, however I want the value of a different column from the same table to be displayed.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Pick up a SQL book and start learning.  Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.  `lc.fullyqualifiedname` in the `SELECT` but not in the `GROUP BY` will definitely error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single `lc.id` there is no need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
select count(pk.id) as "Total",
       min(lc.fullyqualifiedname) as "Name"   -- here agg function
from tsu pk
join location lc                              -- join syntax is preferred
  on pk.locationid = lc.id
where lc.id  = :ID;                           -- filtering with where
```

Alternatively:

```
select count(pk.id) as "Total",
       min(lc.fullyqualifiedname) as "Name",
       lc.id
from tsu pk
join location lc
  on pk.locationid = lc.id
---where lc.id IN (...)
group by lc.id;
```

Comment: Greetings, Thank you for your answer, it worked like a charm, also ideal to modify on short notice.

Will learn from my mistakes haha. I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `lc.fullyqualifiedname` appears in the `select` list but not the `group by` clause, hence `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

```
select count(pk.id) as "Total",
       lc.fullyqualifiedname as "Name"
from   tsu pk,
       location lc
where  pk.locationid = lc.id
and    lc.id  = :id
group by lc.fullyqualifiedname;
```

or better still,

```
select count(*) as "Total",
       lc.fullyqualifiedname as "Name"
from   tsu pk
       join location lc on lc.id = pk.locationid
where  lc.id  = 1
group by lc.fullyqualifiedname;
```

If that isn't what you need then please include some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Greetings, Thank you for your answer. The first one works, secondary gets an error from group. 

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Oops, fixed now.